# Upgrade 12.10 sources.list

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

I have used

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
```

and the like in my `sources.list`. I want to try an upgrade but not sure how to fix my `sources.list` file. This is my backup, but it gives me a load of 404 and no upgrade option. Any way to fix?

– As in: what `sources.list` file to use for an upgrade from 12.10?

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main

# ME ADDED
deb http://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu generic universe
# Spotify
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
# sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys XXXXXXXXX
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install spotify-client
#

deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stable main non-free

deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org quantal main

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ quantal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ quantal partner
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) (I think we could even merge the answer that's here, possibly with *very* slight editing, and it would make a valuable addition--I think this question is asking about an important *part* of what is or *should* be addressed there)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For upgrading, you only *need* to have these lines in your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Everything else, including the Canonical repository and the Extras repository can be (and will be, by the upgrade tool) disabled.

In the future, keep sources that you added in individual `.list` files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory.

Comment: Thanks. I still have problem though, but as it differ somewhat I post a new Q.